# Why doesn't this FormRequest log me in?

Tags: python, scrapy

Complete Python newb here so I may be asking something painfully obvious, but I've searched through this site, the Scrapy docs, and Google and I'm completely stuck on this problem.

Essentially, I want to use Scrapy's FormRequest to log me in to a site so that I can scrape and save some stats from various pages.  The issue is that the response I receive from the site after submitting the form just returns me to the home page (without any login error notifications in the response body).  I'm not sure how I am botching this log-in process.  Although it is a pop-up login form, I don't think that should be an issue since using Firebug, I can extract the relevant html code (and xpath) for the form embedded in the webpage.

Thanks for any help.  The code is pasted below (I replaced my actual username and password):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class dkspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "dkspider"
    allowed_domains = ["draftkings.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.draftkings.com/contest-lobby']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formxpath = '//*[@id="login_form"]',
                formdata = {'username' : 'myusername', 'password' : 'mypass'},
                callback = self.started)

    def started(self, response):
        filename = 'attempt1.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        if 'failed' in response.body:
            print 'Errors!'
        else:
            print 'Success'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your parameters don't match(should be `login` instead of `username`) and you are missing some of them in your `formdata`. This is what firebug shows me is delivered when trying to log in:
[image: Post parameters]

Seems like `layoutType` and `returnUrl` can just be hardcoded in but `profillingSessionId` needs to be retrieved from the page source. I checked the source and found this there:
[image: html sessionid]
so your Spider should look something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return FormRequest(
        url='https://www.draftkings.com/account/login',
        formdata={'login': 'login',  # login instead of username
                               'password': 'password',
                               'profillingSessionId': ''.join(
                                   response.xpath("//input[@id='tmxSessionId']/@value").extract()), 
                               'returnUrl': '', 
                               'layoutType': '2'}, 
        callback=self.started)

def started(self, response):
    # Reload the landing page
    return Request(self.start_urls[0], self.logged_in)

def logged_in(self, response):
    # logged in page here
    pass
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to help.  I tried a bunch of different combinations in including these additional parameters: all, login info + SessionID, login info + SessionID + returnURL, etc.  It still redirects me to the same home page.

Comment: @Baal I've edited my asnwer and tested the spider seems to work. I believe the issue was the `formxpath` argument and since we don't really need any data from the form I got rid of it entirely.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked!  How did you figure out new FormRequest url and what made this formxpath different--and irrelevant--from the usual formxpaths for login forms?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Baal I've figured the url out by inspecting the network tab in firebug (once you click the log in button firebug shows where and what data is being sent so you can reverse engineer it and make a request from it) now for the formxpath, I didn't really check does it really point to the form, but since we didn't need the form I just got rid of FormRequests.from_response() which tries to find form in the web page. So formxpath in this case looks only for the forms that match that xpath, I assume your xpath was incorrect so it didn't find anything. I just replaced it with manual FormRequest object